# Validating booking information

Tags: php, object-oriented, validation

After recently reading up on and watching videos on OO PHP programming I have decided to convert my existing site into OO to gain some experience.

I have successfully (well, I think) converted a page into OOP and would like to know whether this is considered the proper way to implement OOP and whether this should be the way I complete the webpage or whether I need to rethink my design.

Here are the included files, a validate class file, and the "view" I guess, editedbooking.php. (In editedbooking.php a config file is included, which includes validate.php and database.php (my database connection file))

My class file - validatetest.php

```
<?php

class Validations {


public $date2;
public $typeofnumber;
public $phonenumber;


private function validatemobile($mobnumber) {
    $pattern =
            '/^[\(]?(\d{0,4})[\)]?[\s]?[\-]?(\d{3})[\s]?[\-]?(\d{3})$/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $mobnumber, $matches)) {
        // we have a match, dump sub-patterns to $matches
        $number = $matches[0]; // original number
        $a_code = $matches[1];    // 4-digit area code
        $exchange = $matches[2];     // 3-digit exchange
        $ending = $matches[3];       // 3-digit number
        //    $extension = $matches[4];    // extension
        $this->phonenumber = "(".$a_code.") ".$exchange." ".$ending;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Please Enter a valid Telephone Number");
    }
}

private function validatehome($number){
    $pattern =
        '/^[\(]?(\d{0,2})[\)]?[\s]?[\-]?(\d{4})[\s]?[\-]?(\d{4})$/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $number, $matches)) {
        // we have a match, dump sub-patterns to $matches
        $number = $matches[0]; // original number
        $a_code = $matches[1];    // 2-digit area code
        $exchange = $matches[2];     // 4-digit exchange
        $ending = $matches[3];       // 4-digit number
 //         $extension = $matches[4];    // extension
        $this->phonenumber = "(".$a_code.") ".$exchange." ".$ending;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Please Enter a valid Telephone Number");
    }
}

//method to check argument is set
public function is_set($arg1) {
    if (!isset($arg1) && ($arg1 == '')) {
        throw new Exception("Value {$arg1} is not set");
    }
}

//determine whether number is mobile or home phone
public function determine_number($number) {
    if ($number === "mobile") {
        $this->typeofnumber = "mobile";
    } elseif ($number === "home") {
        $this->typeofnumber = "home";
    }
}

//the method below validates a numbers length, length is set to 10 chars by default.
public function validatelength($arg1) {
    if ($this->typeofnumber == "mobile") {
        if (strlen($arg1) != 10) {
            throw new Exception("Your Mobile number is not the right length!");
        }
    } else if ($this->typeofnumber == "home"){
        if ((strlen($arg1) <= 7) || (strlen($arg1) >= 11)) {
            throw new Exception("The input \"$arg1\" is not the required length!");
        }
    } else {
        //error handling in here later
    }
}


//this method has to be passed after method "determinenumber"
public function validatenumber($phonenumber) {
    if ($this->typeofnumber == "mobile") {
        $this->validatemobile($phonenumber);
    } elseif ($this->typeofnumber == "home") {
        $this->validatehome($phonenumber);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Please input a number type!");
    }
}

public function get_number() {
    return $this->phonenumber;
}



public function date_validate($date) {

    $fixingdate = $_REQUEST['date5'];
    $fixingdate = explode("-", $fixingdate);
    $year = $fixingdate[0];
    switch ($fixingdate[1]) {
        case 1:
            $month = "Janurary";
            break;
        case 2:
            $month = "Febuary";
            break;
        case 3:
            $month = "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            $month = "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            $month = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            $month = "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            $month = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            $month = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            $month = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            $month = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            $month = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            $month = "December";
            break;
    } // end of switch
    $month2 = $fixingdate[1];  //for different query (bloew)
    $day = $fixingdate[2];
    $subdate = "The ".$day."th of ".$month." ".$year;
    $this->date2 = "$year-$month2-$day";

    return $subdate;
}

public function servicemethod($service) {
    switch ($service) {
        case 1:
            $service = "Hair Extension - Consultation";
            break;
        case 2:
            $service = "Hair Extension - Application";
            break;

        case 3:
            $service = "Spray Tan";
            break;
        case 4:
            $service = "Eyelash Extensions";
            break;
    }
    return $service;
}

}

$validate = new Validations();
```

"view" page - editedbooking.php

```
<?php
require_once('calendar/classes/tc_calendar.php');

include ('includes/headerBK.html');
require_once('classes/config.php');


if ($session->is_logged_in() == TRUE) {    //main condition - if session isnt set then user isnt logged in.
$name = ucfirst($_SESSION['first_name']);
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$vars = $_SESSION;  //variables passed from login page to sesh var.
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    try {
        //validate the required fields are set
        $validate->is_set($_POST['phone']);
        $validate->is_set($_POST['numtype']);
        $validate->is_set($_POST['date5']);
        $validate->is_set($_POST['optone']);
        $validate->is_set($_POST['opttwo']);
        //determine the type of number being inputted i.e home or mobile
        $validate->determine_number($_POST['numtype']);
        //check the length of the entered phone number and date (just for an extra precaution)
        $validate->determine_number($_POST['numtype']); 
        $validate->validatelength($_POST['phone']);
        //validate number (has to run after "$validate->determinenumber")!
        $validate->validatenumber($_POST['phone']);
        //return the inputted items to a variables.
        $phone = $validate->get_number();
        $subdate = $validate->date_validate($_POST['date5']);
        $service = $validate->servicemethod($_POST['optone']);
        $location = ($_POST['opttwo']);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo output_errormsg($e->getMessage() . "\n");  
    }

    if ($location && $phone && $subdate) {
        $database->autocommit(FALSE); //turn off mysqli auto commit
        $query1 = $database->use_db("INSERT INTO booking_info (location, ph_number) VALUES ('$location', '$phone')");
        if ($query1 == TRUE) {
            $query2 = $database->use_db("INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, date, pending) VALUES ($userid, '$validate->date2', 'yes')");
            if ($query2 == TRUE) {
                $finishpage = TRUE;
                $database->commit();
            } else {
                $database->rollback();
            }

        } else {
            //$database->rollback();
        }

        // first query - adding booking_info


    } else {
        echo output_errormsg("There was a problem with your request");
    }//END OF LOCATION PHONE AND DATE CONDITIONAL


}  //END OF MAIN SUBMITTED CONDITIONAL


if (isset($finishpage)) {  //if this is set then user has succesffully submitted the form already
    echo "Thank you $name, $subdate has been submitted for approval!";
    include('includes/footer.html');
    die();
}


} else {  //redirect as not logged in - MAIN SESSION CONDITIONAL
echo 'You are not logged in. Please click <a href="login.php">here</a>';
include('includes/footer.html');
die();


}  //end of session conditional*/


?>


<script language="javascript">
<!--
function setOptions(chosen)
{
var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');

}
if (chosen == "1") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('On-Site','onsite');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mobile','mobile');
}
if (chosen == "2") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('On-Site','onsite');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mobile','mobile');
}
if (chosen == "3") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('On-Site','onsite');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mobile','mobile');
}
if (chosen == "4") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('On-Site','onsite');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mobile','mobile');
}
}
-->
</script>


<img src="images/topwrapper.png" id="righttopimage"/>
<h1>Book Online</h1>



<div id="contactform">
<form name="myform" action="editedbooking.php" method="post">
    <fieldset><legend>Enter your information in the form below : </legend>
    <P><B>Contact Number:</b><input type="text" name="phone" size="40" maxlength="20" /></p>
    <p><b>Home Phone<input type="radio" name="numtype" value="home" /> Mobile<input type="radio" name="numtype" value="mobile" /></b></p>
    </p>


<table border="0"><tr><td><p><b>Preferred Time : </td><td><?php
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true, false);
$myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
//$myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
$myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
$myCalendar->setYearInterval(2000, 2015);
$myCalendar->dateAllow('2008-05-13', '2015-03-01');
$myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
//$myCalendar->setHeight(350);
//$myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1");
$myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-04", "2011-12-25"), 0, 'year');
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-10", "2011-04-14"), 0, 'month');
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-06-01"), 0, '');
$myCalendar->writeScript();
?>

</b></p></td></tr></table>


<p><b>Please select the service you require : </b></p>
<select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].v    alue);">
<option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Hair Extension - Consultation</option>
<option value="2">Hair Extensions - Application</option>
<option value="3">Spray Tan</option>
<option value="4">Eyelash Extensions</option>
</select><br /> <br />
<select name="opttwo" size="1">
<option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above first</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
</fieldset>

<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit My Information!" \></div>

</form>
</div>


<?php


include ('includes/footer.html');

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let me say, Michael made very good comments which I agree with.

### Minor Comments

1. The first thing I want to see in a class are the important parts.  private methods do not help me interact with the class, so I always write them at the end of my class definitions.
2. Relying on user input can be dangerous:

   public function date_validate($date) {

   ```
   $fixingdate = $_REQUEST['date5'];
   $fixingdate = explode("-", $fixingdate);
   $year = $fixingdate[0];
   switch ($fixingdate[1]) {
   ```

   Someone could modify the request and you wouldn't get date5 as you expected.
3. Creating a global object after your class definition is a bad idea.

   `$validate = new Validations();`

   Create the object where you are going to use it (i.e editedbooking.php)

### Major Comment - Is this OO?

Unfortunately this isn't really OO.  It is a good first attempt.

**Why do I say that?**

Can you think of what Validations represents in the real world?  The closest thing I can think of is that it is a procedure for validating data.  Defining an object by its procedure is a way of still thinking in procedural terms.

You can see this in the `servicemethod` function.  Your object is used as a procedure rather than a method.  You pass in a value and return another one without referring to the object at all.  The same happens with `date_validate`.

**What real world object could have been used?**

I understand you wanting to do validation, that is a good thing (though a little complicated).  A booking or appointment type object might have been easier than a validation class.

**How to make OO validations**

I'm going to leave the implementation blank, but show you the kind of class structure I would use.

I would normally use an interface, but I'm going to skip that considering you are just starting OO.  First the base class which is abstract:

```
abstract class Validator
{
    /** Basic validator.
     *  @param required \bool Whether the value must be set.
     */
    public function __construct($required = true) {};

    /** Return whether the data passed in is valid according to the validator.
     *  @param data \mixed The data to validate.
     */
    abstract public function isValid($data);
}
```

Notice how a common feature is recorded in the base class (whether the value is required).  This feature is shared with all derived classes.

Now, a derived class which can do specific validation:

```
class PhoneValidator extends Validator
{
    /** Return whether the data passed in is valid according to the validator.
     *  @param data \mixed The data to validate.
     */
    public function isValid($data) {};   
}
```

By creating a number of different validation objects you could loop through all of your validations and ensure that they are all valid.

```
// Phone not required, Service implicity required, Date required.
$validations = array(new PhoneValidator(false),
                     new ServiceValidator(),
                     new DateValidator(true));

foreach ($validations as $validation)
{
   if (!$validation->isValid())
   {
       // Code for validation failure.
   }
}
```

The real difference is that these classes now represent real objects rather than straight method calls.

Comment: Thank for very much for the detailed answer! Sorry for the giving the answer so late, having a few PC issues lately.
I am going to try and implement your idea, with a booking class as suggested, and then hopefully move onto the validation class. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

**Design and style**

As a general remark - choose your naming convention and use it consistently.

*Validation*

Public properties are always a bad thing

```
public $date2;
public $typeofnumber;
public $phonenumber;
```

I see just three public methods in validator (see below) All others are internal details of the validator implementation. These methods should return `false` at unsuccessfull validation.

```
public function getValidNumber($number, $typeOfNumber='mobile')
public function getValidDate($date)
public function getValidService($service)
```

*View page*

Defenetely, long way to "view" if you meant MVC. As for now, it has either too much PHP, or too much HTML. Depends on what it is: rather view, or may be template. It has "model"-related parts as well.

It is too big to review it as it is (as volonteer)....

**General notes**

*Security*

You trust too much to globals like `$_SESSION` and `$_POST`. I believe you should add more verifications of their content.

*Programming*

You use exceptions as message carriers. It is not common use. Exception is, well, exception from normal program flow, so it may take a lot of resources, for example, and you will have very expensive message transfer system.

Quite contrary, `try catch` is always a good thing around DB operations, but you don't do it.

`swith` in `date_validate` - don't you think it may be converted into array with boundary validation?

`public function is_set($arg1)` - seems to be too close to `empty()`. What does this statement mean:

```
if (!isset($arg1) && ($arg1 == ''))
```

I believe it is a bug.

`validatehome` and `validatemobile` differ in regexp only. Consider code reuse.